# Keeping ScrollView Position Relative to Items when Layout Changes

Tags: swift, swiftui

I'm trying to create an adaptive layout when switching from portrait to landscape. The problem is when switching to landscape from portrait the scroll position is off. Is there a way to keep the scroll position relative to the items in a scrollview when the layout changes. He is a sample code snippet that reproduces the problem I am facing.

```
struct TestingView: View {
    @Environment(\.verticalSizeClass) var verticalSizeClass
    @State var lastPortraitViewID: Int = 0
    @State var lastLandscapeViewID: Int = 0
    let singleColumn = [
        GridItem(.flexible(), spacing: 12)
    ]
    let multipleColumns = [
        GridItem(.flexible(), spacing: 12),
        GridItem(.flexible(), spacing: 12),
        GridItem(.flexible(), spacing: 12),
        GridItem(.flexible(), spacing: 12),
        GridItem(.flexible(), spacing: 12)
    ]
    var isLandscape: Bool {
        return verticalSizeClass == .compact
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        ScrollViewReader { scrollReader in
            ScrollView {
                LazyVGrid(columns: isLandscape ? multipleColumns : singleColumn, spacing: 12) {
                    ForEach(0..<100) { x in
                        ZStack {
                            if isLandscape {
                                ZStack {
                                    Color.red
                                        .frame(height: 100)
                                    Text("\(x)")
                                }
                                .id(x)
                            }
                            else {
                                ZStack {
                                    Color.blue
                                        .frame(height: 100)
                                    Text("\(x)")
                                    
                                }
                                .id(x)
                                
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            .onChange(of: isLandscape) { _, newValue in
                scrollReader.scrollTo(70)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Tried asking ChatGPT but it didn't help. Also using colors as examples but wanted to show a different CustomView.

//EDIT:
Updated the code that worked for me. Now the thing is it doesn't work when I embed a NavigationStack. Why does it break?

Comment: If the minimum target is iOS17/macOS14, look at `.scrollPosition`. When the verticalSizeClass changes, reset the scrollPosition to where you want.

Comment: @CenkBilgen thanks for responding. I looked into the ScrollViewReader.scrollTo(id). I got It to work, but now the question is why does it break when I embed a NavigationStack?

Comment: I misunderstood, I thought you wanted to keep the current position when the orientation changes, not set it to a default one (70). ScrollProxy can do that (it can't read the position though). For the NavigationStack breaking it, what happens if you use just Grid instead of LazyVGrid?